# What is Event "Visibility" used for?

Tags: google-play-games

I've just started using Events in my Developer Console and am starting to define events for my game. I looked into the developer documentation, but nothing explains the "Visibility" field:

[image: screenshot of "event visibility" form field]

Can someone explain its use? By making it hidden, who is it hidden from?

Comment: I believe it's just whether or not you want the user to know that event has been completed (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/event/Event.html#isVisible())). If visible, it'll probably show up in their profile or something. A reason to keep it hidden, would be maybe some sort of tracking to see how the userbase is doing.